# How to update “row number” column values 1..N after rows are DELETED?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have this table:

[image: TabelName: [dbo].[1202-904200]]

When I make a delete of a box in this table, I need to make an increment of all the following rows.

For example: if I delete BoxNo **'4'** then the rows which are after the last row of BoxNo **'4'** **(5,6,7,..etc)** have to make an increment by 1 and be like **(4,5,6,...etc.).** I hope I succeed in explaining the problem.

Could you please kindly help me to perform this with an SQL Server query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't retrospectively update the values, use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate them at the `SELECT` time. A SQL Table isn't an Excel Worksheet, when you delete it row, they don't all "bump up" one row, tables are by nature unordered.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Its a common pitfall to care about gaps in ids.

Comment: @HoneyBadger This is kind of a Packing List generated by the Barcode Reading Process. after I make the Packing List some of Edits/Corrections have to be done according to the packing process. So, since the box has been deleted the Sum of box number is less by to all the following boxes.

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understood what you meant?

Comment: I don't think its a good practise to update row values while deleting a row in between.
Suppose you have 1000 record in your table, if you delete the 5th record it will update the remaining 995 record , which is very expensive.
Kindly share your requirement to redesign it.

Comment: I didn't understand how to use ROW_NUMBER inside my query. :( @Larnu

Comment: Documentation should be your first stop, @Mark : [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You're completely right @SamimHussain but I don't see any other solution or function to solve this, unfortunately. I have this table which's performing a Packing Process of items by reading the barcodes one by one, and with every read I have a new row inserted with the values of that barcode. Regarding the 1000 rows matter you're right I might have even 9000 rows within the table.

Comment: This is just 1 reason why you shouldn't be doing what you way you want to, @Mark . Calculate the value at run time; don't store it. Wanting to store such values almost(and by almost I mean 99.999% of the time) always infers a design flaw.

Comment: @Mark What Larnu proposes, is to remove this column (RowCounter) from table entirely and calculate its value only while reading data from this table.

Comment: @Larnu infers -> implies

Comment: @Arvo I'm counting on that column to do another function in my related C# Windows From Application, so it's kind of necessary for me :(

Comment: @Mark You can use view (which calculates rowcounter dynamically) in your application (unless you need to write this value back to database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing actions automatically after rows are deleted is what [TRIGGERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are for.

In your case, it looks something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_AfterDelete
ON MyTable
FOR DELETE
AS 
update MyTable set RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
from deleted
     inner join MyTable on MyTable.BoxNo > deleted.BoxNo

GO
```

As you can see SQL Server doesn't raise a trigger after each row deleted but after each DELETE statement execution, which can involve several rows deleted, so we need to use the ["deleted"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-table to apply our action on every one of those rows deleted.

**PS**: This is how what you asked can be done, although I agree with the comments that say that you could structure better this problem instead of needing to update so many rows after every delete.

**UPDATE**

If you want to execute it manually on every delete instruction, instead of automatically on a trigger, you can pass a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to your DELETE statement on C# in order to update the posterior RowCounters. Something like:

```
delete from MyTable where BoxNo = @BoxNo

update MyTable set RowCounter = RowCounter + 1 where BoxNo > @BoxNo
```

Comment: Thank you! could you advise how I can add this to a SqlCommand inside my C# Windows Form Application?

Comment: @Mark I have updated the answer. Is this what you needed to know ?

Comment: your edit is greatly helpful to me thank you, I'll use it, but first I'll make a whole edit to my code, I'll use if statement with SQL query as follows: IF the new insert has the same **BoxNo** _and_ the same **SSCC** _and_ the same **StyleBarcode** THEN the value in **Qty** column will be updated by +1 increment. like that, I will not have the very big rows number and it'll be maximum by 400-500 rows, like that I think I can use your last updated answer without having a design flaw as Larnu indicated (I hope). Frankly, I don't know how to do it yet but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Mark if you get stuck, post a new question and we will try to help you.

Comment: I did actually, and ended up with using  MERGE statements. Thanks.